# Stein Shakarchi complex analysis Ch1 #11 harmonicity of real and imaginary parts

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question about this problem from Stein and Shakarchi's complex analysis text:
[image]

So we will eventually prove that holomorphic functions are infinitely differentiable, but before we do that, shouldn't we have an additional assumption for this problem that the real and imaginary parts are at least twice continuously differentiable? Because being holomorphic only means the first partials exist (for now), but until we prove some further theorems, I am not sure why we can assume the second partials also exist.

Comment: Being holomorphic does **not** mean that only the partials exist; it does mean that they satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations. I don't think this question can be answered with knowledge of C-R, but I could be wrong

Comment: I think you're exactly right. One way to look at this problem is that it doesn't even make sense to speak of something being harmonic or not unless it is twice differentiable. So maybe you're meant to think of this problem as "if the real and imaginary parts are twice differentiable, then..."